# Why employing continuity of the fields of wave does not prevent reflections from numerically truncated domains?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, computational-physics, simulations

In numerical simulations involving electromagnetic waves, absorbing boundary conditions, [Perfectly matched layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectly_matched_layer) etc.. are usually employed to prevent reflection from boundary of the domain. I want to do some simple finite element simulation (using the software  COMSOL Multiphysics) which involves scattering of plane waves from a sphere. I did not specify any boundary condition. My understanding is that such a simulation takes continuity of the tangential and normal components of the fields as the default boundary condition. If so, does this not mean that in such case, the same medium is repeating outside the numerical domain. If so, the wave should not encounter any change in the medium properties and should continue without reflection. Why is this not the case and why do we need to use conditions like PML  explicitly to prevent reflections?

Answer (score 0):

The finite-element method (and many others) discretize the whole computational domain, where the field is sought. Thus, you do not have any access to fields outside of this domain, and the continuity conditions cannot be used on the outside boundary (in contrast to the particle/sphere boundary). Then the only two options are:

1. require field to vanish at the boundary (or some other condition, i.e. impedance one, that considers only the electric and magnetic fields inside the boundary). This is equivalent to placing an artificial boundary, leading to artificial reflections (unless, PMC is used).
2. use periodic boundary conditions, but then you're simulating the photonic crystal (many separated spheres) rather than a single particle.